# jQuery Slideshow with Random Timeouts

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I am trying to set up multiple mini slideshows on the homepage of my site.  If you go there now (http://www.element17.com/), you'll see there's six image categories, and currently some PHP grabs five random images from the database and puts them all in a "slideshow" div.  This seems to be the most popular setup for the jQuery slideshow plugins I've seen.  I would like each of these six to slideshow through the five random images.

What I would like, though, is for the timeout on each slide to be random, so that the six slideshows don't sync up with each other.

I have seen that the Cycle plugin supports this but I have been unsuccessful in implementing it.  I don't need fancy transitions (just fading) and I don't need any other features, so it seems like maybe this would be easiest to do from scratch.  I don't have a lot of experience with jQuery though, so I am hoping that someone can at least get me started?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What went wrong with the Cycle plugin?  You should be able to use it like this (untested):

```
//time in ms
var minTime = 2000;
var maxTime = 5000;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').each(function(ind) {
        $(this).cycle({
            timeout:Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxTime-minTime))+minTime),
            speed:1000
        });
    });
});
```

Just change the min and max times as desired.

Comment: That's almost perfect!  How can I combine your timeout with other parameters for that Cycle plugin?  It seems like when I add another parameter (like speed) it breaks the slideshows.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include setting the speed. If you want to add more parameters, make sure that all but the last are followed by a comma.

Comment: Ah, looking at your page source, what's gone wrong is that you've got the timeout line slightly wrong. It's missing 'Math.floor', and the closing bracket of the floor function as been placed on the next line.

Comment: I removed the Math.floor because I saw no reason to round to the nearest integer.  I've got this figured out now, though.  Thanks for all your help!