# jQuery slideshow with per-slide transitions/durations

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am searching for a jQuery slideshow that supports *per-slide* timeouts and transitions.

From my research, it seems like the [Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) is the closest fit, as it has an appreciable selection of default transitions, and I've even found out how to set per-slide timeouts from this thread:

[jQuery Slideshow with Random Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536130/jquery-slideshow-with-random-timeouts)
(as well as their [FAQ pages](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/timeout.html) on the subject)

However, I do not see a way of setting per-slide transitions, which is a deal breaker. (Short of maybe modifying the existing plugin, which seems like it could be getting in deeper than I'd like)

Can anyone advise on a way to accomplish what I am looking for? I am willing to rewrite the plugin if I have to, but maybe someone knows of a quicker/easier way.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I managed to meet my requirements by generating a list of comma-separated transitions, and passing them as a value of the `fx:` option of the `.cycle` plugin. For reference, I used the FAQ page linked above for the per-slide timings, and the "[This page shows how to use multiple effects on a single slideshow.](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/multi.html)" page for the per-slide transitions.

Comment: I may be on to something. The Cycle Plugin allows you to specify a list of comma-separated transitions. If I can re-use a transition multiple times in this list, it will satisfy my requirements. Posting back soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to meet my requirements by generating a list of comma-separated transitions, and passing them as a value of the fx: option of the .cycle plugin. For reference, I used the FAQ page linked above for the per-slide timings, and the "[This page shows how to use multiple effects on a single slideshow.](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/multi.html)" page for the per-slide transitions.

Answer (score 0):

This is now a lot easier with the [Cycle2 plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/).

For example (not tested, but copied from the [Cycle2 site](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/tile.php)):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.tile.js"></script>

<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-next="#next5"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev5"
    >
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileSlide data-cycle-tile-vertical=false>
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileBlind data-cycle-tile-count=12>
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p3.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileSlide data-cycle-tile-count=4>
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p4.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileBlind data-cycle-tile-vertical=false>
</div>
```

No javascript required!